# ROS Matlab Compressed Image?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Node =
> rosmatlab.node('Test','http://localhost:11311');
> subscriber =
> Node.addSubscriber('/sonar_image/compressed',
> 'sensor_msgs/CompressedImage', 10);
> subscriber.addCustomMessageListener({@test_fun,
> Node.Node});

Good day, I have code as such. It doesn't seem to get anything though. My function does callback test_fun, however, the message returned doesn't seem to have anything

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203940/ros-matlab-compressed-image?/) by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-02-28**:
did you have the `/sonar_image` message defined in your `/usr/local/MATLAB/R20XXa/toolbox/psp/rosmatlab/jars/` ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

okay nvmind im able to get the data, but it's a compressed jpeg object. How do i decompress it in matlab for viewing

---

Originally posted by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) with karma: 61 on 2015-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0